# Bash Script for xls2csv

Tags: linux, bash

Scenario :

A folder in Linux system. I want to loop through every .xls file in a folder.

This folder typically consists of various folders, various filetypes (.sh, .pl,.csv,...).

All I want to do is loop through all files in the root and execute a program only on .xls files.

xls2csv is the program i need to run

for example:

i have 300 directories at /home/ftp_account/user1 up to user300 w/c contains .xls files in every folder,i want to convert all .xls files then move the converted files to /home/ftp_account/user1/converted

take note: converted files for user1 will go to /home/ftp_users/user1/converted

files for user2 will go to /home_ftp_users/user2/converted
files for user3 will go to /home_ftp_users/user3/converted
etc....

Please help!

Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in /home/ftp_users/user{1..300}; do
  for file in $dir/*.xls; do
    fn=$(basename ${file})
    fn=${fn%.*}
    mkdir -p $dir/converted
    xls2csv $file > $dir/converted/${fn}.csv
  done
done
```